# My pointers violate access restrictions errror, and I would like some explanation on what should I do in Book non-default constructor

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I'm doing a homework and I'm trying to follow a class diagram. In Book.cpp file wherever the **commented text** it will cause error saying: `Unhandled exception at 0x00CE3F1B in Lab 1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCD1C`.

In following code I don't know what I should be doing with pointers, I don't know how I should pass this objects variables into this constructor or what I should be doing with it. I'm so confused with c++. I attached class diagram at the end of this post.

```
Book::Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price)
{
    setTitle(title);
    setPrice(price);
}
```

Book.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"

Book::Book()
{
}

Book::Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price)
{
    setTitle(title);
    setPrice(price);
}

void Book::setTitle(string  title)
{
    this->title = title;
}

void Book::setAuthorName(string first, string last)
{
    //pAuthor->setFirstName(first);
    //pAuthor->setLastName(last);
}

void Book::setPublisher(string name, string address, string city)
{
    //pPublisher->setName(name);
    //pPublisher->setAddress(address);
    //pPublisher->setCity(city);
}

void Book::setPrice(double price)
{
    this->price = price;
}

string Book::convertDoubleToString(double number)
{
    return static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << number) ) -> str();
}

string Book::getBookInfo()
{
    return "0"; //title + "\n" + pAuthor->getFullName() + "\n" + pPublisher->getPublisherInfo() + "\n" + "$" + convertDoubleToString(price);
}
```

Book.h file

```
#include "Publisher.h"
#include "Author.h"

class Book
{
    public:
        Book();
        Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price);
        ~Book();
        void setTitle(string title);
        void setAuthorName(string first, string last);
        void setPublisher(string name, string address, string city);
        void setPrice(double price);
        string convertDoubleToString(double number);
        string getBookInfo();

    private:
        string title;
        double price;
        Author *pAuthor;
        Publisher *pPublisher;
};
```

This is what I have in main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    cout << "Book 1" << endl;

    Author *pAuthor = new Author("John", "Doe");
    Publisher *pPublisher = new Publisher("Wrox", "10475 Crosspoint Blvd.", "Indianapolis");
    Book *pBook = new Book("Memory Management", pAuthor, pPublisher, 39.99);

    cout << pBook->getBookInfo() << endl;

    cout << endl << "Book 2" << endl;

    Book book;

    book.setTitle("Advanced C++ Programming");
    book.setAuthorName("Linda", "Smith");
    book.setPublisher("Microsoft Press", "One Microsoft Way", "Redmond");
    book.setPrice(49.99);

    cout << book.getBookInfo() << endl << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
};
```

Author.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Author.h"

Author::Author()
{
}

Author::Author(string first, string last)
{
    setFirstName(first);
    setLastName(last);
}

string Author::getFullName()
{
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

void Author::setFirstName(string first)
{
    this->firstName = first;
}

void Author::setLastName(string last)
{
    this->lastName = last;
}
```

Publisher.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Publisher.h"

Publisher::Publisher()
{
}

Publisher::Publisher(string name, string address, string city)
{
    setName(name);
    setAddress(address);
    setCity(city);
}

string Publisher::getPublisherInfo()
{
    return string(name + "\n" + address + "\n" + city);
}

void Publisher::setName(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

void Publisher::setAddress(string address)
{
    this->address =  address;
}

void Publisher::setCity(string city)
{
    this->city = city;
}
```

Class Diagram because I'm so lost. I believe I did the structure right and some of passing variables is good. But I just don't know how to do it with pointers.

[image]

Comment: You should provide the definition of the classes. Also, why are you storing the author/publisher by pointer? Do you mean to share author/publisher objects for all books that share that property?

Comment: The syntax you use in itself suggest a Java background? If so, C/C++ pointers can be a little daunting. I'd start with making sure all the object pointers are properly initialized.

Comment: I have added class diagram which I must follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your class object has two pointers, one to the publisher and another to the author that are never been initialized. When you try to call the member functions on those objects you are causing undefined behavior and in particular your application crashes.

Comment: I have initialized pointers pPublisher and pAuthor within header file of Book.cpp in Book.h.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: You should post the code, but I very much doubt it. Those look like member variables, and they are not mentioned in the constructor, unless they are globals... you see? Without providing the real code it is impossible to answer. Help others help you: provide full code!

Comment: @HelpNeeder: Where do you *believe* you have initialized the pointers? I am looking at the code and not seeing it. You have *declared* the variables, but there is no initialization in the code in `Book.h` as provided.

Comment: I am adding more code to my post. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: I am not sure you understand what I am telling you. There are two *member* variables `pPublisher` and `pAuthor` that **never** get initialized. You also have variables `pAuthor` and `pPublisher` inside `main` that get initialized, **but** the ones in the object are *uninitialized*. You need to initialize those member variables before calling a member function in them. `void Book::setAuthorName(string first, string last) { pAuthor->setFirstName(first);` in that context lookup will find member variable `pAuthor` (again: uninitialized!) not `pAuthor` inside `main`.

Comment: Ok, I understand now (kind of). How do I initialize this variable now without loosing its content?

Comment: @HelpNeeder Initialization of members is usually done in the initializer list, as part of the constructor.